# PHPUnit: Mocking PDOException->getMessage() method

Tags: php, exception, mocking, phpunit

I am writing a basic PDO wrapper class and when I want to simulate the throwing of an exception by `PDOStatement::prepare()` using `willThrowException()` with the mock of `PDOException` in my unit test, the returned value of `getMessage()` is always and empty string instead of what I set up.

Here is how I tried it:

```
// WrapperClass.php
<?php 

class WrapperClass
{

    private $pdo;
    private $error = '';

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ...';

        try {
            $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            // some value binding and executing the statement
        } catch (\PDOException $pdoException) {
            $this->error = $pdoException->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function getError()
    {
        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

and my test:

```
// WrapperClassTest.php
<?php 

class WrapperClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function save_saves_PDOException_message_in_error_property()
    {
        $pdoMock = $this->getMockBuilder('WrapperClass')
                        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                        ->setMethods(['prepare'])
                        ->getMock();
        $pdoMock->expects($this->once())
                ->method('prepare')
                ->willThrowException($pdoExceptionMock);
        $pdoExceptionMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\PDOException')
                        ->setMethods(['getMessage'])
                        ->getMock();
        $message = 'Message from PDOException';
        $pdoExceptionMock->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getMessage')
                ->willReturn($message);

        $wrapperClass = new WrapperClass($pdoMock);
        $wrapperClass->save();

        $this->assertEquals($message, $wrapperClass->getError());
    }
}
```

I also tried to replace `->willThrowException($pdoException)` with `->will($this->throwException($pdoException))` but it does not work.

I noticed that if I replace `->willThrowException($pdoException)` with `->willThrowException(new \PDOException('Message from PDOException'))` it works but then I'm relying on the `PDOException` class instead of mocking it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Silly thought, but could the order of the declarations matter?  You tell it to throw the pdoExceptionMock, but populate the data after assigning it to your pdoMock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just 2 statements:

1) All exceptions in PHP 5.x extends base Exception and [it defines](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php) 'getMessage' method as final:

```
final public string Exception::getMessage ( void )
```

2) PHPUnit silently do nothing when you try to mock final methods (you can see code that generate mocks [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/src%2FFramework%2FMockObject%2FGenerator.php#L770), `canMockMethod` returns false for final methods)

So

```
->setMethods(['getMessage'])
```

has no effect.

On the other side you don't really need to mock exceptions because they are value objects. Passing `new PDOException('Message from PDOException')` is pretty ok.

Comment: In this specific instance there's no problem not to mock the exception. It becomes a problem however in cases like Guzzle where you have multiple parameters.

For example RequestException:

`public function __construct(
        $message,
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response = null,
        \Exception $previous = null,
        array $handlerContext = []`

Comment: I didn't realize it was final. Thanks for clarifying that.